# Edit plist programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I never remember to change anything when I'm going to production so I just use this method (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1361/_index.html) provided by apple to detect if I'm debugging or in production so all of my changes are made for me (switch to real ads, use the production url etc.)

I have the following plist for Urban Airship

**AirshipConfig.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>analyticsEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>inProduction</key>
    <false/>
    <key>developmentAppKey</key>
    <string>SOMESTRINGHERE</string>
    <key>developmentAppSecret</key>
    <string>SOMESTRINGHERE</string>
    <key>productionAppKey</key>
    <string>SOMESTRINGHERE</string>
    <key>productionAppSecret</key>
    <string>SOMESTRINGHERE</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now for Urban Airship I have to change `inProduction` to `true` when I release to the app store and `false` when I'm debugging

So in my app delegate I'm trying to change the plist with the following if. I'm still trying to get the contents of the plist to see that it's working but I keep getting (null) as my NSLog

```
if([Def AmIBeingDebugged]){
    //Development set to false
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AirshipConfig" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]);
}else{
    //Production set to true
}
```

Any help on setting the correct plist value would be greatly appreciated as I've hit a wall and can't figure out why it's always (null) as I'd think I'd need the contents so I could rewrite the file.

Comment: The plist is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: BTW - you can't write back to the plist file. The app bundle is read-only.

Comment: You cannot change documents that exist in your app bundle. The value you are storing and want to change might be stored more appropriately in NSUserDefaults. You can easily google and change a BOOL in NSUserDefaults by embedding the value in an NSNumber using numberWithBool:

Comment: Or, use `@YES` or `@NO`.

Comment: well I would like to use userdefaults but the UrbanAirship library reads from the plist so I don't think I have the option to use userdefaults

Comment: You should use the [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nspropertylistserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html) to read a plist file, especially if you want to make modifications to it (since it can create mutable containers for you), but in this case it won't help as others have mentioned the plist file in the app bundle is read only.

Comment: Okay so basically I'm just gonna have to remember to switch it when uploading to the app store? Darn O well thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create separate copies of `AirshipConfig.plist` for all of your Xcode build configurations, and name them in the format `AirshipConfig_$(CONFIGURATION).plist` (so e.g. `AirshipConfig_Debug.plist` and `AirshipConfig_Release.plist`). Then update their contents to whatever you want (e.g. set `inProduction` to appropriate values.)

Then create a new "Run Script" Build Phase for your application target in Xcode, and give it the name "Copy Urban Airship config file to bundle". Add this as the contents of the script:

```
cp "${SRCROOT}/MyProjectName/AirshipConfig_${CONFIGURATION}.plist" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/AirshipConfig.plist"
```

This will copy the config file for the correct build configuration into your app bundle, with the filename that the external library expects (`AirshipConfig.plist`). *Just ensure that the source path for the config files is correct in the above example.*

Comment: just a small update, there are two typos in the script you wrote $(SRCROOT) should be ${SRCROOT} and $(CONFIGURATION) should be ${CONFIGURATION}